# Create NTFS report and show whether user accounts are enabled or disabled

Tags: microsoft-excel, permissions, powershell, ntfs

I've been tasked with updating a script that was created by someone else and I'm running into a wall. The script is used to gather NTFS permissions on a specific folder. The script currently outputs the Folder name, Group/User with access to that folder and It's permissions. I'd like to add a column showing if the account is enabled or disabled. For the life of me I can't figure how to get whether the user account is enabled or disabled added into the object. Here is the code i'm currently working with. I've tried to make some modifications to get the Enabled column filled but haven't been successful. Fairly new to powershell so hopefully that made sense!

Thank you

```
$FoldersToCheck = "P:\Companies\"

import-module activedirectory

Function ReportNTFS($p) {
    $temp = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Name -Path $p -Force -Depth 0
    $fullPath += ,$p
    ForEach ($x in $temp) {
        $fullPath += ,($p + $x)
    }
    $Output = @()
    $Properties = [ordered]@{'Folder Name'="Starting Folder: "+$p;'Group/User'='';'Enabled'='';'Permissions'=''}
    $Output += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties
    $Properties = [ordered]@{'Folder Name'='';'Group/User'='';'Enabled='='';'Permissions'=''}
    $Output += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties

    ForEach ($global:Folder in $fullPath) {
        $a,$b = $global:Folder -split $p,2,"simplematch"
#Write-Host "path: "  $b
       $Acl = Get-Acl -Path $global:Folder
       ForEach ($Access in $Acl.Access) {
           $Properties = [ordered]@{'Folder Name'=".\"+$b;'Group/User'=$Access.IdentityReference;'Permissions'=$Access.FileSystemRights}
           $Output += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties

           $thisShortID = $Access.IdentityReference -split "QUANTA\\"
           $groupList = $null
           try { $groupList = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $thisShortID[1] | select name  }
           catch { <# not a group #> }
           finally {
#Write-Host "*is group " 
               ForEach ($u in $groupList) {
                   $Properties = [ordered]@{'Folder Name'=".\"+$b;'Group/User'=' --> '+$u.name;'Permissions'=$Access.FileSystemRights}
                   $Output += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties
                }
           }

      try{
          $global:Enabled = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $thisShortID[1] | where {$_.objectclass -eq 'user'} | get-aduser | select name
           foreach ($user in $global:enabled) { Get-ADUser -Identity $user | select Enabled }
           }
           catch{}
           finally{


                   ForEach ($e in $global:enabled) {
                   $Properties = [ordered]@{'Folder Name'=".\"+$b;'Group/User'=' --> '+$u.name;'Enabled'=$e;'Permissions'=$Access.FileSystemRights}
                   $Output += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties
                   }
                   }

       }
       $Properties = [ordered]@{'Folder Name'='';'Group/User'='';'Enabled'='';'Permissions'=''}
       $Output += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties
   }
    return ,$Output
}


ForEach ($f in $FoldersToCheck) {
    $reportArray = ReportNTFS($f)
}


    $reportArray 
}
```

Comment: You will have to iterate through each user on the machine or the AD domain, determine if each user is enabled or disabled, then compare that list to your list of users from the file.

Comment: Is there anyway to use the list of users already generated from this script and grab it's enabled or disabled status? That's what I was initially trying above but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You iterate user names using ...

```
# Get specifics for a module, cmdlet, or function
(Get-Command -Name Search-ADAccount).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Search-ADAccount).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Search-ADAccount -Examples
<#
# Results

Search-ADAccount -AccountDisabled | FT Name,ObjectClass -A
Search-ADAccount -AccountDisabled -UsersOnly | FT Name,ObjectClass -A
Search-ADAccount -AccountExpired | FT Name,ObjectClass -A
Search-ADAccount -AccountExpiring -TimeSpan 6.00:00:00 | FT Name,ObjectClass -A
Search-ADAccount -AccountInactive -TimeSpan 90.00:00:00 | FT Name,ObjectClass -A
Jeff Phillips               user
Search-ADAccount -PasswordExpired | FT Name,ObjectClass -A
Search-ADAccount -PasswordNeverExpires | FT Name,ObjectClass -A
Search-ADAccount -LockedOut | FT Name,ObjectClass -A
Search-ADAccount -AccountDisabled -ComputersOnly | FT Name,ObjectClass -A
Search-ADAccount -AccountExpiring -DateTime "3/18/2009" | FT Name,ObjectClass -A
Search-AdAccount -AccountDisabled -SearchBase "DC=AppNC" -Server "FABRIKAM-SRV1:60000"
#>
Get-help -Name Search-ADAccount -Full
Get-help -Name Search-ADAccount -Online
```

... so, add this cmdlet to your code as you loop thru the usernames.